# iOS: how to achieve what the contacts app does

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

so I've looked around the forum and can't seem to find an answer fit to my dilemma, i have found very similar ones but i feel like I'm still a couple steps behind the solutions being provided. Yes i am new to iOS i have basic knowledge of objective-c and using X-code, don't think I'm a total noob but to many of you i probably am.

So I'm trying to create an app that effectively will imitate the contacts app on the iPhone.

i am using a master detail application template, therefore the master VC has the main table and the detail VC is to display information.

1. in the detail VC does the contacts app use a tableview with static cells to display info ?
2. if the answer to 1 is yes then how to i get the static cells in the tableview to let the user edit the data field. as i understand the only way to 'edit' a tableview cell is to give it a 'delete' or 'insert' option.

I know that to start off i need to use the setEditing:animated: method to change the view into 'editing' mode, thats fine, its manipulating the actual table to let the user edit the data.

if using a tableview isn't the approach i should be taking please let me know, if i am on the right track i just ask for some guidance.

unfortunately i don't have the 'rep' to post images of what i mean so to make it a little more clear.
i want to go from the 'contacts info sheet' to the editable version of that same 'contacts info sheet', obviously done by clicking the edit button which alternates between edit/done depending on the mode.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a table view is fine is you have a long list of things you want to throw in it but you should note that what the user is allowed to edit/type into in an app like Contacts are NOT labels (which is what is in a `UITableViewCell` by default. Each cell has a `UITextField` or a `UITextView` added as a subview to it and that is what is actually being edited.

This question has actually been asked many times already so here is a starting point for many relevant answers with actual implementation details:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uitextfield+uitableviewcell

Comment: thank you for your help, i guess part of the problem with finding information is asking and searching for the right questions. i will follow what you've given me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts app uses tableViews for both the list and the detail view. The detail is probably made using Dynamic prototypes, because it allow for easy adding and removing rows.

So I suggest you go for Dynamic prototypes for both and incorporate Dima's answer on the textFields and textViews. What you will probably end up is:

- 2 subclasses of UITableViewControllers for the list and for detail
- a subclass of UITableViewCell for each unique row design (prototype)

You can manage the design of a cell prototype completely in IB with AutoLayout, you just need to assign each cell with custom design a unique identifier and a subclass of UITableViewCell class, where you control-drag into to create IBOutlets of individual textfields to be able to reference them in code in your tableview controller.

Comment: will do, thanks for your help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS7 iPhone app - the detail view is not entirely 1 tableview but a view with a couple of imbedded tableviews and a number of dynamically produced links depending on the properties of the contact record (ABPerson). The detail view also has its own detail view depending on the property type.  The Cells in the 2 table views are both custom view cells and all these can be done within UIKit particularly using UITableview UIView and UITableviewcell classes.  These can be understood better if you know the data structure (dictionary like) behind the ABPerson record.

Note: Its not clear if you want to deal with just how the format was constructed or the contact data itself.  If you want to deal with the phone's contacts - look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

There are 2 frameworks one is the Addressbook framework which you have to deal with if you need to get Contact data from the phone. The other is the Adressbook UI framework which pre-builds your interface to the database so you do not have to worry about coding tableviews etc.

Comment: to address the last part of your response, i don't want to deal with the contacts that a user has already within the default contacts app on their personal device. my app although does mimic the basic behaviours of the default contacts app. so i don't think i should be working with the address book frameworks.